# Java Continuing code after JOptionPane

Tags: java, break, joptionpane

So, I'm trying to make a popup message appear when something happens, but I want the code to continue as soon as the message appears, and not wait for the user to press the okay button.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Alert!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
System.out.println("HI!");
```

When I do this, it doesn't print HI! until I press okay. How can I fix this?

Comment: you can't unless you may something tricky running in another thread.

Comment: Create your own, non modal dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate thread and invoke `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` from it:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message", "Alert!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}).start();

System.out.println("HI!");
```

Comment: Thank you! :) This is probably the easiest to implement answer. When the thread finishes(When OK is pressed), it should take care of the garbage collection and stuff by itself, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct... `System.out.println("HI!");` is not reached until it didn't get respond from the message box. Once you clicked **OK** the next line will be executed. Nothing to fix. Java works like that.

Answer (score 0):

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html):

> **All dialogs are modal**. Each showXxxDialog method blocks the caller until the user's interaction is complete.

So you need to show dialog in a separate thread as mentioned above.